# Jump to a page section and execute a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I'm trying to create a FAQ page using Codeigniter + Smarty + javascript

This code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('dd').hide(); 

    $('dt').click(function(){ 
        $(this).next('dd').slideToggle('slow'); 
    });

    $('a.close').click(function (){ $(this).parent('dd').slideUp('slow'); });
 });
```

and my .tpl file is something like

```
<dl>
    <dt>Question one</dt>
    <dd>Answer to question one</dd>
</dl>
```

I am trying to make the page jump to some question based on the url. For example: `www.example.com/faq#q11` jumps to question 11. I do this using `<span id='q11'>` but I now have other problem.  The question opens when I enter the url, I mean if I actually go to `www.example.com/faq#q11` the browser takes me to the question but I have to click it to toggle the answer.

I want that when I enter the URL to some question, it toggles that answer automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this is your ready function:

```
if(window.location.hash)
    {
        //set the value as a variable, and remove the #
        var hash_value = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
        //something like $('#'+hash_value).toggle();
    }
```

edit: not tested but you could probably use `$(window.location.hash)` because `window.location.hash` already contains the ID selecter.

Comment: works perfect, but i changed $('#'+hash_value).toggle(); by $('#'+hash_value).click();

Comment: @user2759595 - if this answer satisfies your question please select it using the green check mark next to it to signify that.

Comment: Its already marked, and i searched through google and Stackoverflow for about 20 minutes and didn't find nothing, maybe my searchwords aren't correct

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done using route services \ modules, and a lot of MVC frameworks out there come with with route services built in.

If you opt for getting this done without a 3rd party library, you can create a simple router function to handle routes for your website on DOMReady:

```
function ifRoute( Hashtag, Callback ){
    if (window.location.hash.indexOf( Hashtag ) != -1)
        Callback();
}
```

Then, on DOMReady, you would use this like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    ifRoute( 'q11', function(){
        //show answer...
        //do other cool stuff...
    });
});
```

This is a very simplistic example, and would only help for DOMReady - but I hope it's enough to help out, and at least point you in the right direction.